# Miller-Rabin test: bug in my code

Tags: d

I've written a [Miller-Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) based on the following pseudo code:

```
Input: n > 2, an odd integer to be tested for primality;
       k, a parameter that determines the accuracy of the test
Output: composite if n is composite, otherwise probably prime
write n − 1 as 2s·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
LOOP: repeat k times:
   pick a randomly in the range [2, n − 1]
   x ← ad mod n
   if x = 1 or x = n − 1 then do next LOOP
   for r = 1 .. s − 1
      x ← x2 mod n
      if x = 1 then return composite
      if x = n − 1 then do next LOOP
   return composite
return probably prime
```

The code I have rarely gets past 31 (if I put it in a loop to test numbers from 2 to 100). There must be something wrong but I can't see what it is.

```
bool isProbablePrime(ulong n, int k) {
    if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) 
        return n == 2;

    ulong d = n - 1;
    ulong s = 0;
    while (d % 2 == 0) {
        d /= 2;
        s++;
    }
    assert(2 ^^ s * d == n - 1); 
    outer:
    foreach (_; 0 .. k) {
        ulong a = uniform(2, n);
        ulong x = (a ^^ d) % n;
        if (x == 1 || x == n - 1)
            continue;
        foreach (__; 1 .. s) {
            x = (x ^^ 2) % n;
            if (x == 1) return false;
            if (x == n - 1) continue outer;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've also tried the variant

```
    ...

    foreach (__; 1 .. s) {
        x = (x ^^ 2) % n;
        if (x == 1) return false;
        if (x == n - 1) continue outer;
    }
    if ( x !=  n - 1) return false;  // this is different

    ...
```

I have a different version of the test that works correctly but it uses modpow. I'd like to have a version that stays closer to the pseudo code that's part of the [rossetta.org task description](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test).

**Edit**: Re: overflow problem. I suspected something like that. I'm still puzzled why the Ruby version doesn't have that problem. It probably handles it differently under the hood.
If I use BigInt, the code does work, but becomes a lot slower than when I use modpow. So I guess I can't get away from that. It's a pity Phobos doesn't have a modpow built-in, or I must have overlooked it.

```
ulong x = ((BigInt(a) ^^ d) % BigInt(n)).toLong();
```

Comment: It looks like Ruby doesn't have that problem because it automatically uses Bignum on impending overflow: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Bignum.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this statement

```
ulong x = (a ^^ d) % n;
```

the quantity `(a ^^ d)` is probably overflowing before the mod operation can take place.  The modpow version wouldn't suffer from this problem, since that algorithm avoids the need for arbitrarily large intermediate values.